# Yarn encore / encore webpack syfmony imposible usar jQuery

Tags: jquery, symfony, webpack, yarn

llevo un buen rato peleandome con esto y no hay manera de hacer funcionar el jquery usando el webpack de symfony.

He seguido este tutorial (creo que es el oficial de symgony) desde el principio:

https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/webpack-encore/require-outside-libs#play

También he seguido los pasos que se indican aquí:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/legacy-apps.html

Pero no veo la manera de hacer funcionar el jQuery en mis archivos.

Pues me salta el siguiente error

> index:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>       at index:11

Es decir que `$`no está definido.

Este es mi archivo `app.js`

```
require('../css/app.css');
const $ = require('jquery');
```

y este es el archivo `webpack.config.js`

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .autoProvidejQuery()
    .autoProvideVariables({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    })
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

No veo la manera de que esto funcione.

Answer (score 0):

En el archivo assets/js/app.js tengo lo siguiente para que me funcione jQuery:

```
var $ = require('jquery');

// create global $ and jQuery variables
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;

var nombre_del_script_sin_sufijo = require('./nombre_del_script_sin_sufijo');
```

En la última línea añado un script que utiliza jquery e incluimos la entrada en webpack.config.js:

```
.addEntry('nombre_del_script_sin_sufijo', './assets/js/nombre_del_script_sin_sufijo.js')
```

Por otra parte has de tener creado el directorio public/build y construir sobre él los assets utilizando:

```
yarn encore dev
```

Reiniciar encore:

```
yarn run encore dev --watch
```

Incluir el archivo assets/js/app.js en la plantilla twig dentro del bloque javascript:

```
{% block javascripts %}
   {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
```

Si sigues teniendo problemas en el archivo webpack.config.js descomenta la línea referida a jQuery:

```
// uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
.autoProvidejQuery()
```

Con esto te debería de funcionar.

Comment: Pero yo por ejemplo no tengo ningún archivo js que utilize expresamente jquery, tengo funciones en las plantillas de twig, voy a probar con `{{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}`

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar correctamente, al añadir un archivo por ejemplo `funciones.js` con funciones que usan jquery y hacer un require en app.js me sale error del encore diciiendo qu eno puede resolver `funciones`

Comment: sigue las instrucciones que da el encore para solventar el error. Normalmente te faltará instalar algo.